# Problem with Remote Powershell ps1 execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Today I have same issue and I cannot find solution, search in WEB read ton articles but without success.
My problem with running PowerShell script on remote machine.
If I run this script locally – it’s works, but remote not.

This is my full story.

```
Server: 
Windows 2008 R2 with SP1 + latest updates
FW – Off
UAC – ON :
-   User Account Control: Use Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account – Disable
-   User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop. – Disable
-   User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode – Elevate without prompting
-   User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation – Disable 
Domain: hardening.com
Hostname: qwerty12345

Version of PowerShell is Installed:

PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5420
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


Client:
Windows 2008 R2 + latest updates
FW – Off
UAC – ON :
-   User Account Control: Use Admin Approval Mode for the built-in Administrator account – Disable
-   User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop. – Disable
-   User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode – Elevate without prompting
-   User Account Control: Detect application installations and prompt for elevation – Disable 
Domain: systemqa.com

Version of PowerShell is Installed:

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4952
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1


•   On Client installed also PowerCLI


1.  On Server , I have file "C:\Windows\Temp\ ConfigurationWinRM.ps1” with following content:
winrm set winrm/config/client `@`{TrustedHosts=`"`*`"`}
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxShellsPerUser="100"}'

2.  My mission run those script on remote “Server” machine. 

3.  I run following script from “Client” machine but get always same errors:
Message = Access is denied.
Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005

a.  Example 1:
$domainCrd = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "$domainUser@$domainNameFQDN",$domainPASS 
$ComputerName = "qwerty12345.hardening.com"

invoke-command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $domainCrd -ScriptBlock { 
    $FileName = "ConfigurationWinRM.ps1"
            $ItemLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\"
            powershell -NoProfile -Command ". $ItemLocation$FileName"
} 

b.  Example 2:
$ComputerName = "qwerty12345.hardening.com"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "**********" -AsPlainText -force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("$domainName\$domainUser",$securePassword)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
            $FileName = "ConfigurationWinRM.ps1"
            $ItemLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\"
            powershell -Command ". $ItemLocation$FileName"

} -Credential $credential

c.  Example 3:
[ScriptBlock] $global:runFile = {

$FileName = "ConfigurationWinRM.ps1"
### $ItemLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\"
$ItemLocation = "$env:windir\Temp\"

& "$ItemLocation$FileName"
} 

RemotePowerShellConnect domain $runFile


WSManFault
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WSManFault:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Message = Access is denied.
Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
Access is denied.
WSManFault
    Message = Access is denied.
Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
Access is denied.
[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\> $error[0] | Format-List * -Force


PSMessageDetails      :
OriginInfo            : qwerty12345.hardening.com
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException:
                        Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
                        Access is denied.

TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RemoteException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandErrorMessage
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        :
PipelineIterationInfo : {}



d.  Example 4:
[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\> [ScriptBlock] $global:www = {
$FileName = "ConfigurationWinRM.ps1"
$ItemLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\"

function Invoke-Admin() {
    param ( [string]$program = $(throw "Please specify a program" ),
            [string]$argumentString = "",
            [switch]$waitForExit )

    $psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
    $psi.FileName = $program
    $psi.Arguments = $argumentString
    $psi.Verb = "runas"
    $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
    if ( $waitForExit ) {
        $proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Invoke-Admin powershell $ItemLocation$FileName"
Invoke-Admin powershell $ItemLocation$FileName

}

[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\> RemotePowerShellConnect domain $www
Session state:  Opened
Session availability:  Available
Running
Service is running ...
You connect to VM Remote PowerShell ...
Invoke-Admin powershell C:\Windows\Temp\ConfigurationWinRM.ps1
[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\>
[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\>

Nothing heppend !!!!! No updates on remote “Server” machine !!! 

e.  Example 5:
.\tmp\psexec -d \\$hostNAME -u $domainName\$domainUser -p $myPASS cmd /C START /WAIT powershell %windir%\Temp\ConfigurationWinRM.ps1

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


cmd started on qwerty12345 with process ID 3860.
[vSphere PowerCLI] C:\>

Nothing heppend !!!!! No updates on remote “Server” machine !!!
```

Comment: any solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in reading that there is just one script file, only on the **local** server, and not on any of the **remote** clients?

If that's the case, then I think you should try this syntax:

```
$FileName = "ConfigurationWinRM.ps1"
$ItemLocation = "C:\Windows\Temp\"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -filepath "$ItemLocation$FileName" -cred $credential
```

I think what's happening when you use the scriptblock syntax is:

1. scriptblock defined on local machine, encapsulated as an object
2. scriptblock object passed to each remote machine
3. scriptblock executed verbatim on the remote machine, therefore it's looking for your script file on the **remote** machine at c:\windows\temp (it doesn't exist so it's throwing some BS access denied error)

Based on the help info the filepath parameter, using -filepath will do the following instead:

1. read in script file locally, convert
   **contents** to a scriptblock object
2. scriptblock object passed to each
   remote machine
3. scriptblock executed verbatim on the
   remote machine, no references to the
   .ps1 file at all at this point